# Adding shared title spanning two plots under another plot with it's own title with R patchwork and ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, patchwork

I have three plots that I would like to format in the following way:

```
 Plot 1
 ------
 P2  P3
```

However, I would like plot 1 to have it's own title, and plots 2 and 3 to share a title that spans plots 2 and 3 and maintains formatting and alignment.

I have the following code:

```
library(patchwork)
library(tidyverse)

econ <- select(economics, -pop, -pce, -unemploy)

econ <- pivot_longer(econ,
                    cols = -date,
                    names_to = "variable",
                    values_to = "value")

gg1 <- 
  ggplot(data=econ, aes(x=date, y=value, color=variable)) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(title="This is a Title",
       subtitle="This is a subtitle",
       y=NULL,
       x=NULL) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom",
        plot.margin = margin(t=.5, b=.5, l=0.1, r=1.2, "cm"),
        plot.title = element_text(margin = margin(b = 5)),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(margin = margin(b = 10)),
        #panel.background = element_rect(fill = "grey90"),
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = "grey"))

gg1

gg2 <- 
  ggplot(data=econ, aes(x=date, y=value, color=variable))+
  geom_line() +
  labs(y=NULL,
       x=NULL) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom",
        plot.margin = margin(t=.5, b=.5, l=0.1, r=1.2, "cm"),
        plot.title = element_text(margin = margin(b = 5)),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(margin = margin(b = 10)),
        #panel.background = element_rect(fill = "grey90"),
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = "grey"))

gg2

plots1 <- (gg2 | gg2) + plot_annotation(
  title = "This is a Title",
  subtitle = "This is a subtitle")
plots1

plotswrong <- gg1 / plots1

plotsissue <- gg1 / wrap_elements(plots1)

ggsave(plot = plotswrong,
       file = "./plotswrong.pdf",
       width = 18,
       height = 38,
       dpi = 320,
       units = "cm")

ggsave(plot = plotsissue,
       file = "./plotsissue.pdf",
       width = 18,
       height = 38,
       dpi = 320,
       units = "cm")
```

When not using wrap_elements, the formatting is correct, but the title is missing. [image: title is missing]

But when using wrap elements, the title is there, but the formatting is ruined. [image: formatting is ruined]

How do I add a title to span plots 2 and 3 without ruining alignment of the axes, creating unnecessary blank space, and losing the background color?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't have a working answer yet, but `wrap_elements(gg1) / wrap_elements(plots1)` is closer to aligned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to add the title for the second row as another `ggplot`. Requires some additional or individual theme adjustments. The most tricky part IMHO is to get the "white" separating lines for which I use an empty ggplot or a `plot_spacer` and which requires some fiddling to set the relative height and width. Additionally note that I have put all plots in a `list` which allows to use `wrap_plots` and use the `design` argument for more control on the placement of the individual plots including the spacers.

```r
library(patchwork)
library(ggplot2)

theme_adjust <- theme(
  legend.position = "bottom",
  plot.margin = margin(t = .5, b = .5, l = 0.1, r = 1.2, "cm"),
  plot.title = element_text(margin = margin(b = 5)),
  plot.subtitle = element_text(margin = margin(b = 10)),
  plot.background = element_rect(fill = "grey", color = "grey")
)

gg1 <- gg2 <-
  ggplot(data = econ, aes(x = date, y = value, color = variable)) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(
    y = NULL,
    x = NULL
  ) + 
  theme_adjust
  
gg1 <- gg1 +
  labs(
    title = "This is a Title",
    subtitle = "This is a subtitle"
  )

gg2 <- gg2 +
  theme(
    plot.margin = margin(t = 0, b = .5, l = 0.1, r = 1.2, "cm")
  )

title <- ggplot() +
  labs(
    title = "This is a Title",
    subtitle = "This is a subtitle"
  ) +
  theme_adjust +
  theme(
    plot.margin = margin(t = .5, b = 0, l = 0.1, r = 1.2, "cm")
  )

list(
  gg1, title, gg2, gg2
) |>
  wrap_plots(
    heights = c(1, 0.01, 0, 1),
    widths = c(1, 0.005, 1),
    design = "AAA\n###\nBBB\nC#D"
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer Stefan. It worked flawlessly! You helped me greatly in improving a set of plots for a report.